# Ldap filter ">=" not working for hyphens in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We have following 3 values in `extensionattribute1` of users:

- -1000
- -7
- *Noon*12

This LDAP filter is only fetching users that have 3rd value in extensionattribute1,

```
extensionattribute1 >= *Noon*12
```

AD performss lexical searches and it should get all the users that have above-mentioned all 3 values.

We are struggling to find a reason for this Active Directory behavior. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` character is a wildcard. So if you want to use it as a literal (as an actual `*` character in the value), you should escape it:

```
extensionattribute1 >= \2ANoon\2A12
```

More details here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx#Special_Characters

However, I don't think that's your issue here.

The rules around what "lexicograhical" means to AD are not made clear in any documentation I could find. In general, it means "alphabetical order". That's great for text, but what that means for symbols is entirely unclear. It definitely does not *always* use their position in the [Unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/en/).

I did some testing of my own. It does rank a period (`.`) higher than a comma (`,`), as you would expect from their positions in the Unicode table. But the hyphen, which is in between the period and comma in the table, AD seems to rank very, very low. It is always less than pretty much everything. I can search for values less than a space character (`<=\20`) and that will match a hyphen.

So, the short answer is that you can't do what you're trying to do. Using `>=` will not give you the results you hope.

You can however, use an OR comparison to find all three of those values, if those are the only three values you want to find:

```
(|(extensionattribute1=\2ANoon\2A12)(extensionattribute1=-1000)(extensionattribute1=-7))
```

Comment: After making your suggested changes to filter, AD is still returning the users with 3rd value.

Comment: I did some testing. I've updated my answer with the results I found.